# Unity - How can i transfer an object from scene1 and instantiate it in scene2?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile

I want to create a simple mobile app in Unity which lets the user select a picture frame and then do some stuff with it.

So, i have a list of prefabs (Picture Frames) in scene1. This scene is shown to the user on app-start.

[image]

Example Picture of how it would look in my app:
[image]

Once the user touches on one of these frames, he gets refered to scene2. This is my code that determines which frames was touched: `FrameSelection.cs` is attached to `FrameList` gameObject.

```cs
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.touches[0];
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
                if (frameList.Contains(hit.transform.gameObject))
                {
                    //Switch scene
                }
            }
        }
```

But how can i pass the selected prefab from scene1 to scene2? I want the prefab only instantiated in scene2 depending on the selected prefab in scene1.

In scene2 i have a script that instantiates objects when the user touches on the screen: `ObjectSpawner.cs`

```cs
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.touches[0];
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                placedObject = Instantiate(objectToSpawn, hitObject.point,hitObject.transform.rotation);
...
```

I tried to avoid destroy on scene switch by using `DontDestroyOnLoad` in my `FrameSelection.cs` script but im still getting a `MissingReferenceException` when scene2 is loaded.

```cs
    void Awake() 
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
    }
```

I would be happy for any help!

Comment: Very detailed question with a lot of good info! Good work. When you get to scene2, check FrameList, is Frame1 still a child of it? And when you store Frame1 in FrameList once it's touched, what var are you storing it in? In other words, when is objectToInstantiate populated?

Comment: @whathm Thank you! I was overthinking this and i could solve it by implementing the singleton pattern which i attached to the frameList. So the selected frame keeps persistent through scene switches.

Comment: Post this as as answer to the question.  @whathm gets credit and I don't have to come and look at it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use Scriptable Objects. They are neat little data containers that can be used to store complex objects. This data persists independently of scenes and classes. They don't involve a lot of extra code and are something that Unity developers need to be familiar with because they do get you out of some nasty holes you can run into when trying to code for persistent data.

[Architect your code with Scriptable Objects](https://unity.com/how-to/architect-game-code-scriptable-objects)

Comment: i would give you 1000 upvotes if i could, thank you so much for this info! This actually solved a lot of issues i was facing with my solution.

Comment: No problem. There is something you need to be aware of, though. It's not always well documented but while Scriptable Objects will reset at runtime, they won't automatically do so in the Editor. So if you have an SO that holds temporary information or state information, you need to make sure that they are reset to default values each time they're run. Although they don't inherit from MonoBehavior, so no Start or Update methods, you can use an Awake method to do your initialisation and resetting. This is something I didn't know for a looong time.

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking this and i could solve it by implementing the singleton pattern which i attached to the frameList. So the selected frame keeps persistent through scene switches. Still thank @whathm